# Word meaning a job someone is installed in where they don’t do anything

Tags: single-word-requests

I’m looking for a word I’m struggling to remember that refers to a job or role which is inconsequential and usually created in order to install someone in a company, not based on their merit.

An example would be creating a vague new role for a friend’s son. The word I’m looking for refers to the actual job itself - it’s a noun that would replace the ‘job’ (e.g “they put so and so’s cousin in a ____”).

I believe the word may not be a strictly formal or technical word but I don’t think it was slang.

Comment: "featherbed", British.  Not the job itself, but rather providing someone with the job.

Comment: Gravy train - An occupation or situation that generates considerable income or benefits whilst requiring little effort and carrying little risk.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

**sinecure**

> A position requiring little or no work but giving the holder status or financial benefit.
>   ‘political sinecures for the supporters of ministers’

[source](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/sinecure)

Comment: There's definitely a more common word than that. But I can't think of it. Good catch.

Answer (score 0):

[No-Show Jobs](https://www.nytimes.com/2012/03/22/nyregion/no-show-jobs-taint-new-york-harbor-waterfront-commission-says.html) and Overstaffing Hurt New York Harbor, a Report Says (NY Times, c.2012)

> Corruption has been ingrained in the docks around New York Harbor for so long that the movie most identified with it was filmed in black and white. But 58 years after the release of “On the Waterfront,” no-show jobs held by relatives of mobsters and other well-connected people continue to vex government officials trying to make the ports more efficient and more competitive.

[No-show Job](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/No-show_job) (Wikipedia)

> A no-show job is a paid position that ostensibly requires the holder to perform duties, but for which no work, or even attendance, is actually expected. The awarding of no-show jobs is a form of political or corporate corruption.

Answer (score 0):

I’m not sure if it’s exactly the phrase you are trying to remember, but the second, derogatory meaning of [job creation scheme](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/job_creation_scheme) is:

> Used in reference to a project or enterprise regarded as serving mainly to keep someone busy and of little value in itself.

E.g. Trump’s presidency appears to be nothing more than a *job creation scheme* for his immediate family.